# C++ error unexplained: error: expected initializer before '&' token

Tags: c++, istream, ostream

i know there's a few other posts like this, but i've been on this single error for over an hour now and can't figure it out. here's the code that's giving trouble

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph& g)
{
    int numVerticies;
    in >> numVerticies;
    g = UndirectedGraph(numVerticies);

    for(int i = 0; i < numVerticies; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        in >> temp;
        if(temp != i)
        {
            g.linkedAdjacencyList[i]->value = temp;
        }
    }

    int edges;
    in >> edges;
    g.edges = edges;
    for(int i = 0; i < edges; i++)
    {
        int first;
        int second;
        in >> first >> second;
        addEdge(first, second);
    }
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, UndirectedGraph& g)
{
    out << g.numVerticies << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < g.numVerticies; i++)
    {
        out << g.linkedAdjacencyList[i] << " ";
    }
    out << endl;

    out << g.edges << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < g.numVerticies; i++)
    {
        out << linkedAdjacencyList[i]->value;
        Node* whereto;
        whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[i]->adj;
        while(whereto->adj != NULL)
        {
            out << " " << whereto->value;
            whereto->adj = whereto->adj->adj;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("hw8.in");

    UndirectedGraph graph;
    inFile >> graph;
```

...

here, the errors are on lines 1 and 28, with the overloading of istream and ostream.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what are lines 1 and 28?

Comment: @Daniel the istream and ostream declarations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
void UndirectedGraph::istream& operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph g)
```

doesn't make sense!  You probably want:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph g)
```

Having said that, you don't seem to be returning anything in your function definition.

Comment: That is true, i completely overlooked that. As suggested, i changed the lines (both istream and ostream) to `UndirectedGraph::istream& operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph& g)` but now i get an expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token
error

Comment: @Jacob: If the edits to your question are representative, then you haven't made the correct changes to your code.  Take another look!

Comment: if it matters, UndirectedGraph exists in a .h file that i am including, and i am overloading from the .cpp file

Comment: @Oli woops! haha i was editing when i saw comments posted so i left it unchanged. should be good now!

Comment: @Oli, you were right, i straight up forgot to return anything. but it still can't get past the `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token` in the declarations

Comment: @Jacob: Oh, hang on.  Have you declared your own versions of `istream` and `ostream`?  If not, then you don't want `UndirectedGraph::istream`, you simply want `istream`.

Comment: @Oli exactly! thanks! the only thing that remains is when trying to use the input operator `UndirectedGraph graph;
 inFile >> graph;`      i get a `(.text+0x280): undefined reference to 'UndirectedGraph::UndirectedGraph()'`    error. i have a default parameterless constructor for UndirectedGraph, so what does this error tell me?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void UndirectedGraph::istream& operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph g)
> ```

There are **two** return types here: `void` and `UndirectedGraph::istream&`. One needs to go. Same goes for the other method.

Furthermore, I assume that you mean `std::istream`, not `UndirectedGraph::istream`, right?

And finally, for this code to work you need to pass the argument `g` **by reference**, otherwise you won’t be able to change it.

Which leaves us with:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, UndirectedGraph& g)
```

Comment: told Charlesworth too, i took out the void in the istream and ostream& in the ostream. now i get another error?


expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘&’ token

Comment: @Konrad: @Wakefield and @Oli got it right, there's no `std::` or `UndirectedGraph::` before either istream or ostream. see comments on Oli's post, i'm receiving a new error when i try to use the input operator

Comment: @JacobL But my answer, unlike theirs, will work – try it! Don’s answer won’t work because `operator >>` can’t be a meaningful member of `UndirectedGraph`. The code may even compile but you won’t be able to use it properly. You really do need to use the code in my answer.

Comment: @Konrad you are correct, both work. But i still have the new error: `(.text+0x299): undefined reference to 'UndirectedGraph::UndirectedGraph()'` that i can't get rid of

Comment: @JacobL This simply means that your class is missing a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of problems. Firstly, are the insertion and extraction operators member methods or just helper functions? For the latter, the signature would be something like

```
istream & operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph &g)
```

For the former

```
istream &UndirectedGraph::operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph &g)
```

In either case, as illustrated above, you should make the *UndirectedGraph* parameter a reference argument. Otherwise, you are just passing in the parameter by value, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of reiterating what @don-wakefield said. I think you want your operators to return std::istream& and std::ostream& respectively (and not UndirectedGraph::istream and UndirectedGraph::ostream).

So the signatures would look like:

```
std::istream& UndirectedGraph::operator>>(istream& in, UndirectedGraph g)
std::ostream& UndirectedGraph::operator<<(ostream& out, UndirectedGraph& g)
```